# Date function not work after host application on server in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to change date base on selected date. I have two Textbox as Start Date and End Date. Base on Start Date i want to add one year in Start Date and display it as End Date.

It is working fine in Locally but after the live enable to select date more then 12. Upto 12 Date it working fine and more then 12th Date it will not work.

**ASPX**

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Start Date:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged1" AutoPostBack="true"  class="form-control" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ErrorMessage="Start Date is Required" Display="None" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vgSave" ControlToValidate="txtDate" runat="server" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"></cc1:CalendarExtender>

</div>

<label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">End Date:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" class="form-control" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ErrorMessage="End Date is Required" Display="None" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vgSave" ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" runat="server" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"></cc1:CalendarExtender>

</div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void txtDate_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
   string  Ds =Convert.ToDateTime(  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(startDate, INDIAN_ZONE)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");



   string yearInTheFuture = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime( Ds).AddYears(1));

        //yearInTheFuture = app.GetdateMMDDYYYY(yearInTheFuture).ToString();

   txtEndDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(yearInTheFuture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Never use `Convert.ToDateTime`. Always use `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void txtDate_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dutchCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", dutchCultureInfo);

    //var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", dutchCultureInfo);


    string yearInTheFuture = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).AddYears(1));

    //yearInTheFuture = app.GetdateMMDDYYYY(yearInTheFuture).ToString();

    txtEndDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(yearInTheFuture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

USed This Code Properly work [image]

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this,

```
protected void txtDate_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string mydateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy hh:m:sstt";
        var myCurrentCulture=CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

        txtEndDate.Text = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, mydateFormat,myCurrentCulture), INDIAN_ZONE).ToString(mydateFormat);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

 protected void txtDate_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime startDate  = DateTime.ParseExact(app.GetdateMMDDYYYY(txtDate.Text), "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

 string yearInTheFuture = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).AddYears(1));

 txtEndDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(yearInTheFuture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.